# how to login as admin in safemode?

Tags: windows-vista, login, administrator, safe-mode

My sister has forgotten her password to vista, however i have installed that system so should know the admin password. However I do not know how to log in as admin. i tried to press ctrl+alt+delete twice in safemode to switch to normal login mode, but its not working.

I heard that admin account is by default turned off in vista, so it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you open an administrator Command Prompt?

If yes, you can type:
net user administrator /active:yes

And that should reveal the Admin account fully.